# Query String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, query-string

By using `document.referrer` we will get all the reference of URL in JavaScript, such as the following:

```
http://localhost/testwordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=thesis-options&upgraded=true
```

From this output how can we extract the query string part only:

```
?page=thesis-options&upgraded=true
```

Is there any method in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to get the values from the query string I use the following function:

```
function getQuerystring(key)
{
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(qs == null)
    return default_;
  else
    return qs[1];
}
```

Simply pass in the key you are looking for and get the value back.
IE: getQueryString('upgraded') would return true

Comment: Note that you may want to change `window.location.href` with `document.referrer`.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: That is a good point. window.location.href will only have what the user sees in it's browser. If you are looking for referrer specific info, it may be better to use document.referrer.

Answer (score 5):

To get the query string from [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer), you can use the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Split) method:

```
var qs = document.referrer.split('?')[1];

if (typeof qs !== 'undefined') {
    // qs contains the query string.
    // this would be "page=thesis-options&upgraded=true" in your case.
}
else {
    // there was no query string in document.referrer.
}
```

Comment: This works in theory, but in practice, pages like Google prohibit the browser to include the parameters if they respect the referrer policy.

Answer (score -1):

There are some functions around to do that. See [this](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) for example.

Comment: Answer needs some code, not only a link.