# Write referrer URL as incoming search term using javascript

Tags: javascript, referrer

Can I extract the search term or keyword of the search engine address using javascript in my html website? I already have made a javascript showing the address of the incoming address of the referrer using the

document.write(document.referrer);

but  I can't figure out how to extract or parse the search term and displaying it it in my website with backlinks for the referrer.

I want to make it a javascript code that could generate the incoming search term for me with backlinks to the referrer. I'm new to JavaScript stuff perhaps you could provide me a simple and understandable steps in making it . Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680328/query-string-in-javascript

Comment: hi i checked the link but I cant understand how to use the query string function . I tried to enclose it in as a  javascipt and inserted it in my website but it did not return any value of the queries made by google when a visitor arrived in my website. I want a simple explanaition about a javascript that writes the incoming search term in as they arrive in my website . thanks for helping

Comment: It's still not clear what you're actually asking. Are you trying to extract a search/querystring out of the referrer?

Comment: Yes. I would like to extract the search term out of the referrer url . I need a javascipt code that could extract and display/write the search term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.referrer.split('?')[1]`

`split` divides the string it's operating on (`document.referrer`) at the character specified (`?`). It creates an array of two elements, the first (index 0) containing the string before the question mark; the second (index 1) the characters after the question mark.

Thus that expression returns the characters after the `?` in `document.referrer`.

Comment: is document.referrer.split('?')[1]  the complete code already that can be used to display the incoming search term for my site? how about the document.write(document.referrer) , how sould I combine it? Im just starting to learn JavaScript programming I hope you could make the explanation more  simple

Comment: That expression gets you what you want. How you use it is up to you. `document.write(document.referrer.split('?')[1])` will output the result.

Comment: Thanks andrew the code worked but it only shows the whole characters after "?".  I was expecting for the search terms typed in the search engine  and not the long characters.  how could I add some parameters that could filter the undesirable character?

Comment: You haven't given any information about what to look for, or the string you actually have. I suggest asking another question along the lines of "I have a string '......': how do I use JavaScript to extract '......' from it?"