# Javascript document.referrer with full querystring

Tags: javascript, url, referrer

I am trying to get the full referring url to a page via javascript.

So far the closet I have come is

```
var lastUrl = document.referrer;
```

This does not include the query attached to the url.

```
var lastUrl = document.URL;
```

returns the current URL with the querystring intact.

Is there anyway of easily obtaining the referring url along with the referring query.

Comment: Could you share us an example?

Comment: document.referrer will bring back for example `http://mydomain.com/paths/file.php`, this being the previous referring page where as I require `http://mydomain.com/paths/file.php?inherit=true&id=123`. Using `document.URL` will bring the full path but of the currently viewed page

Comment: This page might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680328/query-string-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks, but I looked at these - may be able to munge the first answer to something useful though.

Answer (score 9):

You cant. You can navigate user to previous page with

```
window.history.back();
```

but you will not know what url it was. You can get only this:

```
document.referrer
```

i know, it's not full query with url, but it's referrer.

P.s. Would you like, that any page would be able to check where you've been before? Some pages use authentication via url, so anyone would be able to grab those links from your browser's history.

Comment: what did you mean by "any page would be able to check where you've been before" ? How does it affect the browser history, so that anyone could grab that referring link? I only want to know if it's safe to use `document.URL` or `document.referrer` inside a JS file.