# How do I get the full link to a page?

Tags: javascript, http, analytics, http-referer

I need to get the information from where the client came to the site. There is such a property: document.referer, but it displays only the domain as a matter of fact, but I would like the entire link.

For example. We switched from Google search. As you know in Google search, the link is quite long. I would like to receive it.

Only JS. the server is not suitable. Connect Google analytics and so on is not possible.

I not need get params. I need just full link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript document.referrer with full querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682718/javascript-document-referrer-with-full-querystring)

Comment: @marmeladze no. different targets.

Comment: Is your page served in https? most modern browsers follow the origin policy as specified in the origin site, which also dictates what is past in the request. If your source is served in https and yours in http, on most implementations you will only receive the host name but not the path. Some site might even decide that the info not be passed if it is not from the same domain, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the agent making the request as to what they put in this field, it's not in your control as the recipient of the request.

The field is optional, and there's nothing to dictate whether it is blank, contains a partial URL or domain, or the exact URL including all parameters from which the user arrived at your site.

The platform you use to read the field is largely, if not entirely, irrelevant to that.

Note also that since this is in the control of the client, it's very easy to spoof it or provide fake data, or for intermediary services (e.g. proxy servers) to alter the value. It is not something you can realistically rely on for anything important.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer and many other sources online where this is well documented already.